# d3 for loop retrieving data from a list of object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file which load into screen . The csv File has following attributes

```
DATE              MESSAGEID  Status  Source  ParentID  childID
12/21/2013 23:12  123        SEND    A              2
12/21/2013 23:12  456        RECEIVE B              3
12/21/2013 23:12  789        SEND    B              2         4
```

Now in console I wrote this

```
var csvdataset;
d3.csv("newFile.csv",function(d,i){csvdataset=i;console.log(csvdataset)});
```

So it gives me

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

Now if I want to retrieve the message id or any value how do I get those from ?
I know if I give

`d3.csv("newFile.csv",function(d,i){csvdataset=i;console.log(csvdataset[3])});`

I will get the third row but I need some Kind of loop that will execute to retrieve a particular value from an object .

I have tried below things

```
d3.csv("newFile.csv", function (d, i) {
    csvdataset = i;
}, csvdataset.forEach(csvdataset) {
    alert(csvdataset.SOURCE[csvdataset]);
}
});

d3.csv("newFile.csv", function (d, i) {
    csvdataset = i;
    console.log(i.SOURCESERVICE[i])
});
```

but nothing is working .

I have another issue . i am generating a json in tree structure as below

```
[{"Name":"s1","Node ID":"649","DataObject":{"nodeID":"649","nodeName":"s1","timeTaken":"00:06:30","startTime":"2013-12-10 18:06:02"},"Children":[[{"Name":"c1","Node ID":"286","DataObject":{"nodeID":"286","nodeName":"c1","timeTaken":"00:06:27","startTime":"2013-12-10 18:06:04+05:30"},"Children":[[{"Name":"c2","Node ID":"287","DataObject":{"nodeID":"287","nodeName":"c2","timeTaken":"00:00:02","startTime":"2013-12-10 18:06:06+05:30"}},{"Name":"c3","Node ID":"1080","DataObject":{"nodeID":"1080","nodeName":"c3","timeTaken":"00:06:17","startTime":"2013-12-10 18:06:12+05:30"},"Children":[[{"Name":"c4","Node ID":"b2861a2f-75a9-4f95-abcd-1dae54e713bc","DataObject":{"nodeID":"b2861a2f-75a9-4f95-abcd-1dae54e713bc","nodeName":"c4","timeTaken":"00:05:08","startTime":"2013-12-10 18:07:19+05:30"}}]]}]]}]]}]
```

now i am trying to create a tree in d3 . But i am unable to retrieve the children

```
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
   .size([height, width])
     .children(function(d)
        {
            return (!d.Children || d.Children.length === 0) ? null : d.Children;
        });
   d3.xhr("DataMapper?function-name=Tree","application/json", function(error, flare) {
   root = JSON.parse(flare.response);
   root.x0 = height / 2;
   root.y0 = 0;
   console.log(root);
   function collapse(d) {
        if (d.Children) {
          d.Children= d.Children;
          d.Children.forEach(collapse);
          d.Children= null;
           console.log("children "+d.Children);

        }
      }
 });
```

if i am giving`var nodes = tree.nodes(root);` i get a array of nodes in the nodes variable but if i give `var links=tree.links(nodes);` i am unable to get the links . Could any one explain this .I have provided the json above

Comment: Looping will cause you some pain to be honest. What are you trying to do with the data? Make it into a table?

Comment: any solution for the tree issue

Comment: any update on the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to loop in the `d3.csv` function defined in the second argument.

So you can for example do the following:

```
d3.csv("newFile.csv",function(d) {
    d.forEach(function(entry){ alert(entry.name)});
})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i tried it it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of null " if i am using i.foreach its showing the values. Am i doing it correctly?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I did a mistake, if you use 2 arguments, the 1st one is the error message, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

D3 is designed to be functional where you concentrate on the data not the loops.

```
var data = [];
d3.csv("newFile.csv", function(csvData){
    data = csvData;
    // Call a function now you have the data ready 
    doSomething(data);
})

function doSomething(d){
d3.select('#target')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(d)
    .enter()
        .append('div')
        .text(function(d, i){return d.MESSAGEID + ' ' + d.Status;})
 }
```

For further reading check out this

```
var data = [];
d3.csv("newFile.csv", function(csvData){
    // Just  array of data which has been parsed from the file
    data = csvData;
    console.log({'02: data just Parsed':data});

    // Say you want to group by Status(could be d.MESSAGEID, d.Source etc)
    data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){return d.Status;})
        .map(csvData);
    // Now returns an object with 'RECEIVE':Array[1] & 'SEND':Array[2]
    console.log({'03: Nested by Status':data});

    // Call a function now you have the data ready 
    // doSomething(data);
})


// This returns Array[0] as d3.csv does not block 
console.log({'01: Outside callback': data});
```

Comment: if suppose i need to build a tree with the above data i am tried to create a  `var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .sort(null)
    .children(function(d)
    {
        return (!d.childID || d.childID.length === 0) ? null : d.childID;
    });` and then tried to take the nodes = tree.nodes(csvdataset) and then the links var links = tree.links(nodes) but i am not getting the nodes and links .I am thinking as it is storing every row in the form of objects so that is causing the issue.[link](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/07/building-a-tree-diagram-in-d3-js/ ) i was following this link as a reference.

Comment: another question i had is is it possible to take the time difference between two timestamp for a each parent node.

Comment: A [quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Dgx/) on how to parse the dates from string using d3. Also worth checking out [the documentation on time intervals in d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals)